# Mouse disconnecting and programs not closing and more

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage, virtual-memory, connection

My mouse keeps disconnecting and reconnecting as well as my usb modem. My programs don't always close when i tell them to and even when I use task manager. T

hey are also using all my RAM for a lot of the time. These problems got worse after I installed iTunes and uninstalled. I not sure if they related. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a myriad of issues, but it's possible that you have a virus. I would either try running an anti-virus program, such as Microsoft Security Essentials:

> http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/

and seeing if that helps.

You could also try doing a system restore of your computer and then follow that up with a Windows Update. Also, if you're able to, go into your control panel and see if your USB drivers are working.